# Invalid XPath: string-join(.//div[@class="static"]/text(), "")?

Tags: xpath, scrapy

The following works and produces a list:

```
xpath('.//div[@class="static"]/text()')
```

i want to return a single string instead

i tried:

```
xpath('string-join(.//div[@class="static"]/text(), " ")')
```

and

```
xpath('.//div[@class="static"]/string-join(text(), " ")')
```

both are invalid, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Why not just do `' '.join(foo.xpath('.//div[@class="static"]/text()').extract())`?

Comment: that's plan B, i need to know how xpath works, xpath breaks up a single paragraph into a list by new lines, i want it to not do that

Comment: `string-join()` is an XPath 2.0 function, however scrapy only supports XPath 1.0, there is no equivalent XPath 1.0 function. So the suggested Plan B seems like your best option...

Comment: Thanks Tobias! I noticed it was an xpath 2.0 function but "scrapy xpath 2.0" didn't return anything useful.

Comment: You can also try `xpath('string(.//div[@class="static"])')[0]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Use

   ```
   '\n'.join(response.css("div.static::text").extract())
   ```
2. Use processors in item loaders: this is by far the most elegant solution if you use this a lot: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html.